# How to get nearby tiles from a location?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps-api

I want to get the tile in which a particular location lie and also its nearby tiles.
Is there any google map api which could return this information.

Comment: Would you try to improve the question with more context, and tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: i've got the tile in which the location exists through calculations but i want to get it through a google api to maintain its accuracy. is there any such api in google?

Answer (score 1):

Since Google doesn't allow direct tile access, and OpenLayers only wraps the Google JavaScript API, it's unlikely that this is possible. With another tile provider, like OpenStreetMap, MapBox, or MapQuest Open, this would be possible through OpenLayers or another API.

Comment: This is good correct information.